# Laravel Storage not finding file

Tags: laravel

Laravel is not finding my file.  I have a file with the following path:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\IRB Source\storage\app\documents\Consent_Document.docx
```

I am trying to copy this file into a new file.  I have the following in my controller:

```php
File::copy(storage_path('app/documents/' . $document), storage_path('app/project/' .$id. '/' . $document));
```

When I debug with the following command:

```php
dd(storage_path('app/documents/' . $document))
```

I get the proper path above.  But Laravel is saying no file exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because directory `app/project/{$id}` is not created yet.

You can ensure directory exists before copying as the following way:

```php
$file = storage_path("app/documents/{$document}");
$dir = storage_path("app/project/{$id}");
if (!File::isDirectory($dir)) {
  File::makeDirectory($dir, 0755, true, true);
}
File::copy($file, "{$dir}/{$document}");
```